# Android custom UI dialog theme not working

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i am trying to apply a theme to all AlertDialogs that pop up in my app and have created the necessary

```
    <style name="Theme.jon" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> theme in my styles.xml file below:

<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/jon.dialog</item>

</style>

<style name="jon.dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">21dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_corners</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_grey</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@style/jon.ButtonBar.AlertDialog</item>
    </style>

    <style name="jon.ButtonBar.AlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Holo.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_searching_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/margin_40dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_grey</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    </style>
```

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jon.jon">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name=".LibraryApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.jon">

        <service
            android:name=".net.networklib.NetworkService"
            android:exported="true"/>

    </application>
```

here is how i typical show a dialog

```
/**
     * Construct error message dialog
     *
     * @param context
     * @param title
     * @param message
     * @return
     */
    private static AlertDialog getErrorDialog(Context context, String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        return builder.show();
    }
```

Not sure what is missing but my dialogs doesnt change its apperance

Comment: Apply this `Theme` to your `Activity` too..

Comment: Doesnt applying it to application , applies it to all activities?\

Comment: Yup try to apply to your `Activity`

Comment: Have tried to apply stle on activity and it did not work

Comment: Replace AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

with
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,R.style.Theme.jon);

Comment: So there is no way to apply a theme to all alerDialogs ?

Answer (score 4):

In your declaration of `Theme.jon`, replace

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/jon.dialog</item>
```

with

```
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/jon.dialog</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace Below Line

```
 <style name="Theme.jon" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

with

```
 <style name="Theme.jon" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Thats it....